# FEdora 17, Install specific Kernel version using yum

Tags: kernel, yum, fedora-17

how can i install a specific version kernel version, I want to install kernel-3.6.11-1fc17.x86_64, however when using yum, it is saying no package available

Answer (score 0):

That means that that particular kernel isn't available in the distribution's repositories anymore. If the kernel was installed before (check with `rpm -q kernel`) it might still be around (by default, `yum` keeps 3 versions), so you can still boot into it.

Kernels are updated (like any other packages) when serious problems are found, you are well advised to keep up. What exactly are the reasons why you want that kernel?

Comment: how can i get that specific kernel version, I'm trying to install ATI CAtalyst, i've kernel 3.7, its not working, from what i've heard it works with kernel 3.5

Comment: There was a recent question about how to fix a hang caused by Catalyst...

Comment: can you reference me with the link??